# Make key of inner list vs value of outer list

Tags: java, java-8

I have list of user and each users (id , name and List)has list of Address(aId,name).

I want to make a map based on address id as key and user as value.?? How to make it.
Map<String,User>

Comment: What if several users share the same address?  Perhaps it should be a map <String, List<User>>?

Comment: Yeh Alex it has only unique users. It's one to one mapping

Answer (score 1):

If the users do not share their addresses, this task can be resolved using `flatMap` for the users' addresses to convert them to the stream of `Map.Entry<String, User>` and then collecting using plain `Collectors.toMap`:

```java
Map<String, User> userByAddress = users
        .stream()
        .flatMap(user -> user.addresses.stream().map(a -> Map.entry(a.aId, user)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue
        ));
```

If there are some rare cases when several users share the same address, a merge function may be needed to resolve conflicts:

```java
Map<String, User> userByAddress = users
        .stream()
        .flatMap(user -> user.addresses.stream().map(a -> Map.entry(a.aId, user)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                (user1, user2) -> user1  // keep the address assigned to the initial user
        ));
```

Similarly, it is possible to use `merge` function of `Map`:

```java
Map<String, User> merged = new LinkedHashMap<>();
users.forEach(user ->
        user.getAddresses().forEach(a -> merged.merge(a.aId, user, (u1, u2) -> u1)));
```

---

If many users share the same addresses, it may be worth to build a map `<String, List<User>>` using `Collectors.groupingBy`:

```java
Map<String, List<User>> usersByAddress = users.stream()
        .flatMap(user -> user.addresses.stream().map(a -> Map.entry(a.aId, user)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())
        ));
```

*Note: the examples above use Java 9 [`Map.entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-) method to create a map entry, which may be replaced with `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(a.aId, user)` if only Java 8 is allowed*

Answer (score 0):

Just use nested `for` loops:

```java
Map<String,User> userMap=new HashMap<>();
for(User user:users){
    for(Address ad:user.getAddresses()){
        userMap.put(ad.getId(),user);
    }
}
```

It iterates through all addresses of every users and adds an entry with the id of the address as key and the user object as value.

Comment: What is more users share the same address id? The duplicated keys are not allowed and must be handled. I'd point it out in your answer.

Comment: The OP didn't mention that but he explicitely said he wants a `Map<String,User>` so multiple users cannot be saved for a single key, anyways.

Comment: That's true. But consider **both** `user1` and `user2` will have among addresses list one with id i.e. `addressId123`. Therefore 2 entries `addressId123=user1` and `addressId123=user2` would be put into the map causing the `user1` value gets replaced. I would rather suggest to the OP the following structure `Map<String, User>` or at least inform about this design flaw.

Comment: Yes, one could inform the OP but it is not necessarily a design flaw and I decided not to because the question was just about getting a `Map<String,User>`.